# How to save json returned from axios in a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm, axios

I want to save the json returned from axios into a variable. Currently I can only see it when I console.log(response.data) with the following code:

```
function status() {
  const url = "https://api.com";
  axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
  });
}
status(); // console.logs object successfully
```

If I just set response.data to a variable instead of logging it, it stays blank ( {} ).
I want to do something like this:

```
let data = {};
function status() {
  const url = "https://api.com";
  axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
    data = response.data;
  });
}
status();
console.log(data); // {}
// I want to manipulate and use the properties of data in subsequent code here
```

How may I accomplish this please? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Not familiar with axios, but have you tried using async/await? It might be that the console.log() is firing before axios actually returns.

Comment: Also, it would probably be nicer to have the data be returned from the status() function. To do that, pop the data variable inside the function and return it after the axios call has finished.

Answer (score 5):

The function `axios.get(url)` returns a `Promise`. You can use `async/await` like so.

```
 async function status() {
  const url = "https://api.com";
  let response = await axios.get(url);
  return response.data;
}

status().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error when I try this: "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: @kylel9506 - you have to mark the function `async`, like so `async function status() {  ... }`

Answer (score 2):

Axios executes an asynchronous operation. Any async operation always executes after all synchronous operations are executed. Read about JavaScript execution here: https://medium.com/@gaurav.pandvia/understanding-javascript-function-executions-tasks-event-loop-call-stack-more-part-1-5683dea1f5ec

Long story short, the `console.log` statement in the end is a sync operation which will always execute before `axios(...).then` callback.

JavaScript has a new feature however called `async...await` which allows you to run Promises in sequence like regular JavaScript statements. But please do note that it is still asynchronous execution in play.

```js
async function status() {
  const url = "...";
  consr resp = await axios.get(url);
  return resp.data;
}

status().then(data => console.log(data));
```

In regular JavaScript this is equivalent to this:

```js
function status() {
  const url = "...";
  return axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
    return resp.data;
  });
}

status().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Edit: To store an access data outside wrap everything inside a self executing async function and do the following:

```js
(async () => {
  let data;
  function status() {
    const url = "...";
    return axios.get(url).then((resp) => {
      return resp.data;
    });
  }
  data = await status();
  console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I am looking for though. How can I save the data as a variable after the status.then() like this: ```let obj = {};
status().then((data) => (obj = data));
console.log(obj);```

Comment: It will be saved only once async operation is completed... You can only access the ``data`` inside the ``then`` callback. Not outside of it as in your case.

Comment: However, you can wrap your code in Self executing async function and use await on ``status`` function to solve your problem. Check my edit on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The axios.get(url) is an asynchronous method, which means it will not return the result but a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (an Object that means "It do not have the result, but I will get it eventually"). To get the result, you have to wait for it.

You have multiple options for that, the first one is using **.then()** (not really recommended)

```
axios.get(url).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The second one require using async/await. Async is used to define an asynchronous method, await is used to wait for an asynchronous method. You can only use await in an asynchronous method (as you.. well, have to wait).

```
const result = await axios.get(url);
console.log(result);
```

However, as said above, if you are in top module function (if you're not in a method for example, just right in your .js file), you can use immediately invoked function like this :

```
(async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(result);
)();
```

Et voilà !

Answer (score 1):

Since a call to the API is async (takes some time to return an answer) you should **wait** for this answer before continuing with your code. Luckily js has a nice feature to do this with a nice syntax. It's commonly known as [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

You just wrap your code in a async function which you call initially. Then update your status function to an async function to await for the axios response, hence await for the status function to finish populating your data variable.

```
(async () => {
  let data = {};
  async function status() {
    const url = "https://api.com";
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    data = response.data;
  }
  await status();
  console.log(data); // {...response.data}
  // Now you can manipulate and use the properties of data in subsequent code here
})()
```

Here a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/andresabadia/f8z5bq0L/7/)